# Sending two email using javascript and mail-gun

Tags: javascript, html, mailgun

I have created account on mail-gun website then I have email and password  to add in javascript  code to be able to send receive email when someone fill the form and submitted but I'm the only who is receiving  email and I want to send thanks email to someone  who  submitted from the form.

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password");
```

Comment: You might want to look in the mailgun interface and see in the logs if the e-mails are being rejected there. If you see no mention of your friends e-mail addresses there, then the problem might lie in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send an email using JavaScript.
Here are steps.
first i recommend to use Mandrill
Step 1: Get an API key
Sign up here https://mandrill.com/signup/
then click on Get API Keys
Step 2: Load jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 3: Use the $.ajax function to send an email
Make sure you’re using POST to submit your data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: “POST”,
  url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
  data: {
    ‘key’: ‘YOUR API KEY HERE’,
    ‘message’: {
      ‘from_email’: ‘YOUR@EMAIL.HERE’,
      ‘to’: [
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_1@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          },
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_2@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘ANOTHER RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          }
        ],
      ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
      ‘subject’: ‘YOUR SUBJECT HERE!’,
      ‘html’: ‘YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!’
    }
  }
 }).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
 });
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782

Comment: Can you summarize the solution you are proposing in the answer? Links have a tendency to die.